# Eclipse floating windows on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: eclipse, macos-sierra

Good day.
I am currently new to this forum, hopefully you guys will bear with me.
Anyways, I am currently facing a problem in Eclipse Neon running in Mac OS X Sierra. Specifically on its Floating Windows.

Usually I have 2 or more floating windows Eclipse IDE and they are spread across monitors with separate spaces. So some is on the left screen and the other is on the other.
Everytime an intellisense pops up or I open project properties all of those floating windows will go to one side of the screen where the main window is located.

This problem didn't happen to me when I was still using Eclipse Mars 2 in Mac OS X El Capitan.

Your opinion or assistance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I am also having this exact same issue.  So I'm going to add a bounty.

Comment: The only solution I found to this problem was to downgrade to ElCapitan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best work around I could find is to switch off "Displays have separate Spaces" under mission control settings as noted int this answer from superuser.  https://superuser.com/a/670222/86375

This is unfortunate as it removes the ability to use separate spaces per monitor entirely.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Justin Ohms. I also have read in Eclipse docs that Eclipse (including 10.11) only has tested it until 10.11 (El Capitan). But I will try it again later with Oxygen.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your Eclipse to Eclipse Oxygen. I cannot find a specific patch, but it may help. [Dowload Eclipse Oxygen](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/M5/eclipse-java-oxygen-M5-win32.zip)

Comment: Thanks @Eric He, I tried Oxygen last month but it won't work. I was reading that Eclipse (including 10.11) only has tested it until 10.11 (El Capitan). But I will try it again later with Oxygen.